# Exception while deleting Spark temp dir in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run unit test of spark job in windows 7 64 bit. I have

```
HADOOP_HOME=D:/winutils

winutils path= D:/winutils/bin/winutils.exe
```

I ran below commands:

```
winutils ls \tmp\hive
winutils chmod -R 777  \tmp\hive
```

But when I run my test I get the below error.

```
Running com.dnb.trade.ui.ingest.spark.utils.ExperiencesUtilTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.132 sec
17/01/24 15:37:53 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
17/01/24 15:37:53 ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: C:\Users\415387\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b1672cf6-989f-4890-93a0-c945ff147554
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Users\415387\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b1672cf6-989f-4890-93a0-c945ff147554
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:65)
        at .....

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=786m; support was removed in 8.0

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:525)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
```

I have tried to change the permissions manually. Every time I get the same error.

Please help!

Answer (score 26):

The issue is in the ShutdownHook that tries to delete the temp files but fails. Though you cannot solve the issue, you can simply hide the exceptions by adding the following 2 lines to your `log4j.properties` file in `%SPARK_HOME%\conf`. If the file does not exist, copy the `log4j.properties.template` and rename it.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=ERROR
```

Out of sight is out of mind.

Comment: The problem with ignoring this is that the undeleted temporary files pile up and use up disk space, and most people are not likely to look in this directory to find them.

Comment: Correct buddy - out o sight is out of mind. Very true.

Comment: @UncleLongHair Its always a good habit to remove the temp folder every once in a while by going to cmd and typing %temp% and deleting everything, so its fine i believe.

Comment: @Sumukh, can you please update your answer with how this works with log4j2? There is a log4j2.properties.template file but copy/rename + adding the two lines does not seem to hide the exceptions.

Comment: @KaiRoesner see a more recent answer in the same post, below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76753660/2516301 
I had the same problem as you and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The lines below should hide the error on Windows for **log4j2**

```
logger.shutdownhookmanager.name = org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager
logger.shutdownhookmanager.level = OFF

logger.sparkenv.name = org.apache.spark.SparkEnv
logger.sparkenv.level = ERROR
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing the same problem after trying to run the WordCount example with *spark-submit* command. Right now, i'm ignoring it because it returns the results before the error happens.

I found some old issues in spark Jira but didn't found any fixes. (BTW, one of them is with the status closed.)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8333

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12216

Unfortunately seems that they don't care about spark on windows at all.

One bad solution is to give the Temp folder (in yout case *C:\Users\415387\AppData\Local\Temp*) permission to everyone.

So it will be like that:

```
winutils chmod -R 777 C:\Users\415387\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

But I **strongly** recomend you to **not** do that.

Comment: I changed the permissions of the Temp folder to see it that was the issue, but it didn't work. Also, I tried to specify a different working dir with --conf spark.local.dir, with a directory I know I have permissions, but it didn't work either. So this is definitely not a permissions issue. If someone has a solution, please share.

Comment: You can also change the location of this temp dir by setting the "java.io.tmpdir" Java System property, so you can put it someplace else that you feel comfortable changing the permissions.

Comment: You can try `MD D:\temp` and `SET SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\temp` before starting `spark-shell`.

Answer (score 4):

I have a workaround for this, instead of letting spark's `ShutdownHookManager` to delete the temporary directories you can issue windows commands to do that,

Steps:

1. Change the temp directory using `spark.local.dir` in `spark-defaults.conf` file
2. Set `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF` in `log4j.properties` file
3. `spark-shell` internally calls `spark-shell.cmd` file. So add `rmdir /q /s "your_dir\tmp"`

this should work!

Answer (score 3):

I've set the HADOOP_HOME variable in the same way as you have. (On Windows 10)

Try using the complete path when setting permissions i.e.

D:> winutils/bin/winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive

This worked for me.

Also, just a note on the exception - I'm getting the same exception on exiting spark from cmd by running "sys.exit".

But... I can exit cleanly when I use ":q" or ":quit". So, not sure what's happening here, still trying to figure out...

Comment: what is "D:>" ?

Comment: That's just a prompt on Windows cmd, currently sitting in D: drive. That's where I had kept my winutils.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Mine is "C:\>“

Answer (score 2):

Running Spark in windows has this deleting Spark temp issue. You can set it as follows to hide it.

`Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.FATAL)`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem. I changed the permission to \tmp folder instead of \tmp\hive

D:>winutils/bin/winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp

Not seeing any error after this and there is a clean exit

Answer (score 1):

After following above suggestions, I made below changes -

Update **spark-defaults.conf** or create a copy of spark-defaults.conf.template
 & rename it to spark-defaults.conf

Add following line like -
**spark.local.dir=E:\spark2.4.6\tempDir**
via above line we are setting the temp folder for Spark to use.

Similarly update **log4j.properties** in your spark setup like did above, with the below lines-

**log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=ERROR**

Now ShutdownHookManager will not be used during exit causing those error lines on console.

Now how to clean the temp folder then?
So for that add below lines in **bin/spark-shell.cmd** file -

**rmdir /q /s "E:/spark2.4.6/tempDir" 

del C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi*.***

By having above updates, I can see clean exit with temp folders clean-up also.

Answer (score 0):

I create a directory `d:\spark\temp`

I give total control to Everybody on this dir

I run

```
set TEMP=d:\spark\temp
```

then I submit my jar to spark and watch the directory on the explorer.

Many files and directories are created/deleted but for one of them there is an exception.

Imho this is not a right problem.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: D:\data\temp\spark\spark-9cc5a3ad-7d79-4317-8990-f278e63cb40b\userFiles-4c442ed7-83ba-4724-a533-5f171d830913\simple-app_2.11-1.0.jar

this is when trying to delete the submitted package. It may not have been released by all involved process.

Answer (score 0):

My Hadoop environment on Windows 10:

```
HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop
```

Spark and Scala versions:

```
Spark-2.3.1 and Scala-2.11.8
```

Below is my spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --class SparkScalaTest --master local[*] D:\spark-projects\SparkScalaTest\target\scala-2.11\sparkscalatest_2.11-0.1.jar D:\HDFS\output
```

Based on my Hadoop environment on Windows 10, I defined the following system properties in my Scala main class:

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\")
System.setProperty("hadoop.tmp.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\tmp")
```

Result: I am getting the same error, but my outputs are getting generated in the output path D:\HDFS\output passed in spark-submit

Hope this helps to bypass this error and get the expected result for Spark running locally on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

for python:

create an empty dir tmp\hive

```
import os
os.system(command=f"path to \\bin\\winutils.exe chmod -R 777 path to \\tmp\\hive")
```

Answer (score 0):

For log4j2.properties, the following snippet seems to do the job (of hiding the error)

```
logger.1.name = org.apache.spark.SparkEnv
logger.1.level = ERROR
```