# How to disable all logging info to the spark console from .net application

Tags: .net, apache-spark, logging, console, log4j

How could I show results without logging in console?
While running execution I have like this, but with many rows:

```
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/C:/
20/08/28 13:35:27 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
```

Unfortnately to me, there is no result after my manipulation. I found file log4j.properties.template, change everything to WARN and stiil have the same issue. Also I changed date time format to check if file was read.But format was stil the same, like `log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n.`
So, that is why I decided this file was not read.
Also I wrote in my .cs file

```
var sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf());
            sc.SetLogLevel("WARN");
```

in my code like this

```
namespace mySparkApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            //Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

            var sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf());
            sc.SetLogLevel("WARN");

            // Create a Spark session
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .Builder()
                .AppName("word_count_sample")
                .GetOrCreate();

            // Create initial DataFrame
            DataFrame dataFrame = spark.Read().Text("input.txt");

            // Count words
            DataFrame words = dataFrame
                .Select(Functions.Split(Functions.Col("value"), " ").Alias("words"))
                .Select(Functions.Explode(Functions.Col("words"))
                .Alias("word"))
                .GroupBy("word")
                .Count()
                .OrderBy(Functions.Col("count").Desc());

            // Show results
            words.Show();

            // Stop Spark session
            spark.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Then reboot my machine, but I have the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename/copy the file `log4j.properties.template` to `log4j.properties`.

If you want to see fewer logs, you can set the logging level to `ERROR` instead of `WARN`.

You can also put these lines to avoid logging the other errors you got.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=ERROR
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825871/exception-while-deleting-spark-temp-dir-in-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: Did everything, but the same

Comment: Issues before output table were deleted, but extra logging rows after the table stil there.

Comment: @AntonGriduhsko do the settings in my edited answer help?

Comment: No. You can try this tutorial https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/data/spark-tutorial/install-worker The technology is very crude.

Comment: These lines: log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=ERROR smth like this should be inserted in log4 config template in config folder. But they dont work.

Comment: @AntonGriduhsko did you make sure that you inserted those lines into the log4j.properties file, NOT the template file?

Comment: I dont know exactly. The matter was that after your advice I broke my results. I had only mistakes. Thats way I return my changes back. So I don t want to do something strange any more.

Answer (score 0):

So...my struggle was:

1. to delete template word from log4..blalalal.template from folder conf
2. comment like # the last 2 rows in this file and add

   log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager=OFF
   log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.SparkEnv=OFF
3. set OFF everywhere.

The result is better but still annoys me.
Because app eats all exceptions.

```
C:\Users\User\mySparkApp>%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master local bin\Debug\net5.0\microsoft-spark-2.4.x-0.10.0.jar dotnet bin\Debug\net5.0\mySparkApp.dll
20/12/27 22:29:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2020-12-27T19:29:39.8205092Z] [USER-PC] [Info] [ConfigurationService] Using port 51569 for connection.
[2020-12-27T19:29:39.8243891Z] [USER-PC] [Info] [JvmBridge] JvMBridge port is 51569

+------+-----+
|  word|count|
+------+-----+
|  .NET|    3|
|Apache|    2|
|   app|    2|
|  This|    2|
| Spark|    2|
| World|    1|
|counts|    1|
|   for|    1|
| words|    1|
|  with|    1|
| Hello|    1|
|  uses|    1|
+------+-----+
```

I don t think, that I am done, because if you have exception - so then you need to see them, but...

For test this could be as a decision.
Thanks to all, who took part in conversation. Decisions were really ununderstandable. But thanks.